# Trying to use loops and add to a variable

Tags: python

I want to create a while loop to prompt the user if they would like to enter a living cost.  The user would input 'y' for yes and the loop would proceed.

I this loop I would like to add up all the living expense entered and once the loop ends to store to the total amount in `total_living`.

Example would be

```
l_cost = input('Enter living cost? y or n ')
while l_cost != 'n' (loop for living cost)
 totat_living = (keeps adding until I say all done
 l_cost = input('Enter living cost? y or n ')
```

Other while and for loops for different scenarios
`total_exp = total_living + total_credit + total_debt` ect ect

I just need a little help with this as to how to add up multiple values and then maintaining the total value for the loop that I am in.

If someone could point me to an example of a function or loop that is similar or tell me where to look that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using `while` as below:

```
flag = input ("wish to enter cost; y or n" )
total=0
While flag != 'n':.
     cost = int(input ("enter cost: "))
     total = total + cost
     flag = input("more ?? Y or n")
print(total)
```

Comment: This is what I wanted! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
total_cost = 0.0
prompt = 'Enter a living cost? y or n: '
answer = input(prompt)

while answer.lower() != 'n':
    cost = input('Enter your cost: ')
    total_cost = total_cost + float(cost)
    answer = input(prompt)

print('Total cost is $' + str(total_cost))
```

Comment: Thank you! - I just had a hard time trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
def checkout():
    total = 0
    count = 0
    moreItems = True
    while moreItems:
        price = float(input('Enter price of item (0 when done): '))
        if price != 0:
            count = count + 1
            total = total + price
            print('Subtotal: $', total)
        else:
            moreItems = False
    average = total / count
    print('Total items:', count)
    print('Total $', total)
    print('Average price per item: $', average)
checkout()
```

## Note

## Try to convert this example to your problem.